# Convert SAS DATE and use in a PROC SQL

Tags: sas

I'm having problems to DATEs in SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1 M4.

it's very very simple in SQL Server or VBA but in SAS is driving me crazy.

Problem:
For some strange reason I'm unable to make a simple select. I tried many different forms of formating and convertions but any seems to work
My Simple select returns no observations.

Description of **T1.DT_DATE** in proc contents
Type: Num
Len: 8
Format: DDMMYY10.
Informat: DATETIME20.

```
%let DATE_EXAMPLE='01JAN2019'd;

data _null_;
      call symput ('CONVERTED_DATE',put(&DATE_EXAMPLE, ddmmyy10.));
run;

%put &CONVERTED_DATE;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE TEST_SELECT AS 
        SELECT * 
        FROM MY_SAMPLE_DATA as T1
        WHERE T1.DT_DATE = &CONVERTED_DATE
;QUIT;
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiran.
It gave me a clue to solve the problem.

Comment: I Finally understand.
SAS date internally is a 5 lenght number, as you said, data literal is the way SAS comunicate. DDMMMYYYY'd or DATE9

But the main situation rely in this "D" in the last position, so I had figured out how to solve the problem

cats("'", put(DATE_EXAMPLE, date9.), "'d")

So this works in my new variable, passing to a proc sql no print : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intially you are setting up the date properly but you are changing it to a different value that is not understood in where clause. See the resolutions of macrovariable for both macrovariables you have created

```
%put value of my earlier date value  is &DATE_EXAMPLE;
value of my earlier date value  is '01JAN2019'd
%put value of my current date value is &CONVERTED_DATE;
 value of my current date value is 01/01/2019
```

change your code to use date literal that is '01JAN2019'd then your code will work. 01/01/2019 value will not make sense in where  clause.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TEST_SELECT AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM MY_SAMPLE_DATA as T1
    WHERE T1.DT_DATE = &CONVERTED_DATE
;QUIT;
```